# keydown, keypress event on window.print

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

See this http://jsfiddle.net/24g3b2c1/

Select the text and then click on 'PRINT'. Then press 'Enter' key.
two events are fired keydown and keypress.

Now comment window.print, only one event is fired 'keydown'

Is this expected behavior in chrome ?

```
<body>
    <div id="print_key" style="display:block;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select: none;user-select:none">
        PRINT
    </div>
    <div id="txbx" contenteditable=true>
        <p>
            <span>Select this text. Then click on PRINT and press (char / enter) key.</span>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    var printKey = document.getElementById('print_key');
    printKey.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);
    printKey.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
    printKey.addEventListener("keypress", keyPressHandler, false);
    printKey.setAttribute('tabIndex', -1);
    function clickHandler(event) {
        document.getElementById('print_key').focus();
    }
    function keyDownHandler(event) {
        console.log('key down on print key')
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        window.print();
    }
    function keyPressHandler(event) {
        console.log('keypress on print key')
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
</script>
```

My observations:-

- On firefox event.preventDefault() in keydown prevents keypress
- While in chrome event.preventDefault() in keydown prevents keypress when window.print is not called, else keypress is called

Why this difference in behaviour just by calling window.print ?

Answer (score 0):

Move event.preventDefault(); after window.print, only keydown will be fired

Comment: but why does is it depend on whether event.preventDefault is called after or before calling the print function on window ?

Comment: because the print function fires a keypress event in chrome.. Thats how chrome is written.

Comment: ok, if the print function fires a keypress event in chrome, this would be a separate event right ? I am not able to understand how does calling event.preventDefault() after window.print() avoids the 'keypress'